# How to change the alignment of z-axis label with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, z-axis

I have a 3D plot and would like to push the z-axis label, drawn vertically, downwards because it overlaps the scale factor placed by `ScalarFormatter`.  The latter doesn't have obvious options to set the position of the scale factor or provide a reference for the scale factor text.  So now I am looking to push the z-axis label downward.

z-axis labels don't support the `loc` option, although the doco implies it does (it says "see `set_yabel`"). The z-axis label position does not respond to `horizontalalignment` or `verticalalignment` options. Extra spaces at the end of the label don't help either, even math mode spaces.

I can get a reference to the label, it current position is (0.5, 0) which is before transformation I guess, but setting its position makes no difference. It does have a transform set according to `is_transform_set()`, but I really don't want to go down the path of changing its transform.

Any idea of an easier way to do this?

Comment: By "drawn vertically, downwards"  do you mean rotate the z axis?  If so you can try:                     
     ax.set_zlabel('$Z$'',  rotation=90)

Comment: @Akroma the label is drawn parallel to a vertical axis. I want to translate it in the -z direction, not rotate it